# Python не видит гиперссылки в ворде

Tags: python, ms-word

Есть вордовский файл, в нем есть таблица на 4 строки 9 столбцов, в 6 столбце идут (начиная со второй строки) почты, и если почта не выделяется вордом как гиперссылка, то питон прекрасно все считывает и переводит в текст, но если выделяется, то мне выводит пустоту, как исправить?

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('file.docx')
table = doc.tables[0]
print(table.cell(2,6).text)
```

Comment: Дайте пример таблицы, чтобы дать конкретный ответ. А так можете найти инфу на [github issues](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/85#issuecomment-917134257). Либо через `RT.HYPERLINK`

Comment: @Dmitry Пример особо и не нужен, просто создайте любую таблицу внутри ворда, и внутри одной ячейки вставьте любую ссылку, вот пример, у меня таблица ничем особым не отличается. А на счёт github issues спасибо, вроде нашел там решение, но надо его ещё правильно использовать.

Comment: Ну, что ж. Для понимания - существование входных тестовых данных увеличивают шанс получить конкретный верный ответ. В вашем коде вы обращаетесь к ячейке, что там? Гадать на кофейной гуще не у всех есть такой дар. Поэтому мы и хотим иметь хоть какие то входные данные, чтобы понять где вы ошибаетесь. Но выбор за вами.

Comment: @Dmytry часть для понимания понял))), "В вашем коде вы обращаетесь к ячейке, что там?", если вы спрашиваете про конкретику, то, как я написал выше, подойдет любая ссылка, то есть у меня в одной из ячеек стоит даже google.com, для проверки, главное, чтобы сам ворд помечал это как ссылку, но ответ, полностью меня удовлетворяющий на данный момент, я как раз сейчас потестил с github issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем и целом, если меня не подводят знания англ. языка, то [github issues](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/85#issuecomment-917134257)
здесь описана как раз та же проблема, и люди, покопавшись внутри самой библиотеки нашли проблему. Когда библиотека обращается к ворду к тексту с гиперссылкой, то ворд возвращает более комплексный ответ, чем ожидалось, и библиотека, не в состоянии обработать это, просто возвращает пустое значение. Если говорить о решении, то мне подошло решение "roydesbois", вот его код:

```py
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
import re
Paragraph.text = property(lambda self: GetParagraphText(self))
def GetParagraphText(paragraph):

    def GetTag(element):
        return "%s:%s" % (element.prefix, re.match("{.*}(.*)", element.tag).group(1))

    text = ''
    runCount = 0
    for child in paragraph._p:
        tag = GetTag(child)
        if tag == "w:r":
            text += paragraph.runs[runCount].text
            runCount += 1
        if tag == "w:hyperlink":
            for subChild in child:
                if GetTag(subChild) == "w:r":
                    text += subChild.text
    return text
```

После этого опять `import docx as` ###, или просто `import docx` (как в моем случае)
и гипертекст внутри ячеек становится читабельным программой

Comment: Отлично, разобрались. Мои поздравления